# Is it legal/ethical to post production code?

Tags: legal, ethics

This may sound silly or obvious but this is my case; I work at a company that recently implemented SAP and I was the responsible to generate/migrate the master data of the company which let me learn a lot from this system. SAP comes with its own language known as ABAP and since the system went live I've been learning and programming with it. Before ABAP I worked as a freelancer in other projects with VB6, VB.Net, C# and ASP.Net building a lot of stuff, here I've made some utilities that are been using daily, so I came with long experience in programming.

At first ABAP was difficult but eventually after long analysis, googling and trial and error I became the guy who makes basically all the development in SAP from reports, to user-exits, enhancements, BADIs, tables, dynpros, etc. Daily I learn more and more because of all the requests I receive which makes me investigate and code a lot everyday. It has become challenging and funny at the same time. You could be very productive in ABAP once you get into.

Ok, the question is - can I post how I resolved a certain thing in SAP? That implies that I'd publish production code. I feel doubtful about this.

Comment: You can always post how you solved a problem without publishing direct code snippets. However, the company you work for (in all the countries I've worked in) owns the code you produced, so you'd need permission from someone there I'd think.

Comment: I find the question surprising.  Can you not simplify, cleanse, rewrite or otherwise make the code **not** production code?  Blogs contain mountains of explanations, code fragments, code summaries, code rewrites.  Why can't you "cleanse" the code?

Comment: @S.Lott - Depending on the law where he lives, and the contract he signs, his employer may still own that "clean" rewrite, and not want it published.

Comment: @Craige: That would be a bizarre situation.  It's not the code.  Since it's not a copy, it would be very, very difficult to show that a blog posting had any relationship at all to work performed for an employer.  Even if the employer had a heavy-handed "all intellectual property developed here belongs to the company" contract, it would be very, very hard to make any kind of legal claim when the code does not match.  You can't copyright ideas.

Comment: @S.Lott - Joel Spolsky made a great write-up on this on  Startups: http://answers.onstartups.com/a/20136. Basically, your employer COULD own code you write on your own time. In such a situation, the employer would also own the rewrite.

Comment: @Craige: That remains true.  But.  It's a bizarre situation that needs to be clarified by **updating** the question with the situation.  It's not clear why cleansing, sanitizing, rewriting or summarizing aren't the first choice here.

Comment: @S.Lott: it is not that simple because in my case it would reveal internal details that are specific to the company business, and this discussion makes me clear that is better to not post this kind of things. I produced that code and the knowledge and experience are mine but (the code) belongs to my employer.

Comment: "it would reveal internal details that are specific to the company business".  You've said that without offering any explanation of why this is **necessary**.  You keep repeating it without providing any evidence.  If you cannot sanitize, cleanse, summarize or otherwise remove details, then, you're not talking about "code".  You're talking about "business process".

Comment: Gentlemen, you're stretching the comments into a protracted debate.  It may be better to take this into a chat. FWIW, there are legal ramifications regardless of whether code is cleansed or not which boil down to how permissive the company culture is when dealing with this sort of thing. I've provided an [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/134481/39178) along these lines below.

Comment: Did you really just use legal and ethical as synonyms? ;)

Comment: I am sort of with S.Lott, but it takes work to properly clean & obscure things up. Say you work for an accounting firm, but your examples are about apples and sheep. If you do not do something drastic each time such as replacing accounts with sheep, then over time one can get a picture of what the business/work is like. If someone really wanted to, then they could probably infer your address, your name from the web site, then figure out who your employer is. Then they could get an idea what the company is doing, what issues it is having. Something as innocent as "10 billion apples" is a clue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say that it is clearly wrong to publish code you have written as part of your contract with your employer.  That code is owned by your employer and you probably don't have either the legal or the ethical right to publish it.

Publishing knowledge you've gained as part of your employment is a much greyer area.  Broadly I would suggest that;

- If it's knowledge you've learnt for yourself, not relating to proprietary systems, then it's probably okay to write a code snippet from scratch and publish that.
- If it's knowledge you could only have gained by working for your employer than you probably should not publish it.
- If it's knowledge relating to proprietary company systems then you should not publish it.

Bottom line is that if you are concerned then talk to your management and get their, preferably written, consent before you do so.

Comment: +1 for "talk to your management". Can't get any more clear than hearing it straight from the horses mouth.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on a lot of things, but if its just a short segment of code that anyone could reasonably expect to implement, then ethically I'd say its ok, you still may be violating copyright law though. Copyright laws are really grey and open to interpretation when it comes to code.

The thing you really need to watch for is parts of code that use a certain algorithm that may be patented or a trade secret, things that fall into this category should be fairly obvious though.

It should be obvious, but changing variable names and removing comments specific to your place of employment (TODOs) should be done if they use terms with special meaning to your company.

Answer (score 2):

As long as its not proprietary information or a proprietary problem being solved then it should be easy enough to change your production code to make a generic example of the problem being solved.  Be very careful however to cleanse the code of anything proprietary or identifiable.

I'm not saying to post production or proprietary code, I'm saying use that as a base to make a generic example to illustrate a solution to the problem posed.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally accepted that any code written for your employer belongs to your employer.  Even if you take production code, and clean it up so that it is something else that you aren't using in production in order to post it on a blog or on a Q/A site, your employer still owns the code.

In most cases, there is generally little harm in posting small snippets of code for the purposes of solving problems.  Your boss should accept that you sometimes need to go outside the company to seek help when you can solve the problem entirely in house. If your intention however was to post something interesting to a personal blog, you may find yourself on shaky ground.

The best way to cover yourself both ethically and legally is to send your boss an email asking for permission to post your code snippets (cleansed or otherwise).  Even better, ask your boss what the company policy is when it comes to posting code snippets to blogs and Q/A sites, and what your reasoning is, then leave it to your boss to tell you what is permitted.  Try to get this in writing as either a letter/email or in a policy document - such as an employee hand book.

Answer (score 1):

It is common for "work for hire" types of contracts to have a clause where you as an employee give up the copyright. There are some local variations to what extent you give up the copyright, but as a general rule you are not allowed to publish code or other documents that is specifically owned by the company as that would become a copyright violation.

That said, you can go usually around the problem by writing an example instead. You should ask the management of the company about posting it as well if you believe it is too close to production code. Try to reason by leaning towards goodwill and that you're not revealing any production code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be very hesitant to do such a thing, and should certainly consult with management to make sure that, legality or ethics aside, it's something of which they approve.

On the other hand, illustrating a technique using a code structure you developed is perfectly ethical. Usually production code is not the clearest example of a technique anyway, since domain variables and extraneous function calls stand in the way of making your point as clearly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're that worried about it, just ask your employer.  Say, "I get a lot of programming help on a site called Stack Overflow.  I just wanted to make sure you're okay with occasionally posting small snippets of code in my questions and answers."

In my experience, they're unlikely to object, especially for code that's only incidental to your work or only used once then thrown away, like migration scripts or utilities.  I've had them okay even more substantial working code, like a plugin or module for third party software.